# How do I choose between Pipe, Queue, Value, Array and Manager to communicate between processes?

Tags: python, process

In python, it supplies a lot of ways to communicate between processes in module multiprocessing, `Pipe`, `Queue`, `Value`, `Array` and `Manager`. Which of them are better choices?

Answer (score 14):

Use Pipe and Queues if you want to implement message-passing.
Use Value and Array if you want to implement shared memeory.
Use Managers if you want to expose an object-oriented interface to multiple processes.

`Pipe` is good for 1-to-1 communication or for byte-level protocols:

- Pipe can be either bidirectional (“duplex”) or unidirectional
- Pipe is not concurrency safe: only one process can use the same end of the Pipe; it is good in 1-to-1 communications, otherwise it requires locks
- Pipe may transmit pickable Python objects or raw bytes
- The buffer size cannot be specified

`Queue` is similar to a unidirectional Pipe, but may work in many-to-many scenarios:

- Queue is unidirectional: first in, first out
- Queue is concurrency safe: multiple processes may use the same end of the Queue; so it is good when there are multiple producers or multiple consumers
- Queue may transmit only pickable Python objects
- The maximum size of the Queue may be specified
- "Whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed before the process is joined."

Queue is implemented using a pipe and some locks/semaphores.

`Value` and `Array`:

- provide synchronized access to shared data
- work only with C data types (`ctypes`)

Managers:

- may be used on various data types: they return proxy objects which expose the same methods as the underlying (shared) object
- can handle remote access

`Value` and `Array` is a lightweight approach to shared memory. In my experience, the overhead of using a `SyncManager` and `AutoProxy` [can be huge](https://gist.github.com/astanin/9191089). If you can solve your problem using a `Value` or an `Array`, use them. `SyncManager` may be useful to expose an object-oriented interface to multiple processes, unless it is not called too frequently.